# How to use Spring MVC to update current user data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I'm beginner to learn spring MVC, Now I have a problem can't solve. I spent a lot of time want to use Spring MVC to update current user data,but always go round in circles.

**For Example login user is [test2] and I want to update mAccount and mPassword,how to get login session and click jsp form to update.What should I do?(mId is Primary Key)**

**eclipse console message:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi8rE.jpg)

**eclipse debug mode message:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vYB0.jpg)

Bean:

```
private Integer mId;
private String mAccount;
private String mPassword;
private String mName;
private Date mDate;
private String mPhone;
private String mAddress;
private String mGender;
private String mEmail;
```

MemberController:

```
    @Autowired
MemberService memberservice;

@Autowired
ServletContext context;

@RequestMapping(value = "/checklogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Login(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request) {
    MemberBean mb = null;
    Map<String, String> errorMsgMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    session.setAttribute("errorMsgKey", errorMsgMap);
    String mAccount = request.getParameter("mAccount");
    String mPassword = request.getParameter("mPassword");

    try {
        mb = memberservice.checkPassword(mAccount, mPassword);
        if (mb != null) {
            session.setAttribute("LoginOK", mb);
        } else {
            errorMsgMap.put("LoginError", "帳號不存在或密碼錯誤");
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        errorMsgMap.put("LoginError", e.getMessage());
    }

    if (errorMsgMap.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
        return "login/login";
    }
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRegisterData(Model model) {
    MemberBean mb= new MemberBean();
    model.addAttribute("MemberBean",mb);
    return "register/register";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String porcessAddNewRegistertoForm(@ModelAttribute("MemberBean")MemberBean mb, BindingResult result) {
    memberservice.registerMember(mb);
    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateMemberForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String AddLoginMemberBeantoUpdateForm(Model model) {
    MemberBean mb = new MemberBean();
    model.addAttribute("MemberBean", mb);
    return "register/updateMember";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateMemberForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String UpdateMember(@ModelAttribute("MemberBean")MemberBean mb, BindingResult result ) {
    memberservice.updateMember(mb);
    return "index";
}
```

MemberDao:

```
public void setConnection(Connection conn);

public boolean checkAccount(String mAccount);

public int registerMember(MemberBean mb);

public MemberBean queryMember(String mAccount);

public MemberBean checkPassword(String mAccount, String mPassword);

public void updateMember(MemberBean mb);
```

MemberDaoImpl:

```
@Override
public boolean checkAccount(String mAccount) {
    boolean exist = false;
    String sql = "FROM MemberBean m WHERE m.mAccount=:mid";
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        MemberBean mb = (MemberBean) session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("mid", mAccount).uniqueResult();
        if (mb != null) {
            exist = true;
        }
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        exist = false;
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException ex) {
        exist = true;
    }
    return exist;
}

@Override
public int registerMember(MemberBean mb) {
    int n = 0;
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(mb);
    n++;
    return n;
}
@Override
public MemberBean queryMember(String mAccount) {
    MemberBean mb = null;
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "FROM MemberBean m WHERE m.mAccount=:mid";
    try {
        mb = (MemberBean) session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("mid", mAccount).uniqueResult();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException ex) {
        mb = null;
    }
    return mb;
}

@Override
public MemberBean checkPassword(String mAccount, String mPassword) {
    MemberBean mb = null;
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "FROM MemberBean m WHERE m.mAccount=:mid and m.mPassword=:pswd";
    try {
        mb = (MemberBean) session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("mid", mAccount).setParameter("pswd", mPassword)
                .uniqueResult();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        mb = null;
    }

    return mb;
}

@Override
public void updateMember(MemberBean mb) {

    String hql="UPDATE MemberBean mb SET mb.mAccount = :mAccount mb.mPassword = :mPassword WHERE mId = :mId";
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("mAccount", mb.getmAccount()).setParameter("mPassword", mb.getmPassword())
            .setParameter("mId", mb.getmId()).executeUpdate();

}
```

}

MemberService:

```
boolean accountCheck(String mAccount);

int registerMember(MemberBean mb);

MemberBean queryMember(String mAccount);

public MemberBean checkPassword(String mAccount, String mPassword);

void updateMember(MemberBean mb );
```

MemberSeriveImpl:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void updateMember(MemberBean mb) {
    if (mb.getmAccount() != null && mb.getmPassword() != null) {
        dao.updateMember(mb);
    }
}
```

updateMember.jsp:

```
    <form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="MemberBean">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>帳號:</td>
                <td><form:input id="mAccount"  path="mAccount" type="text" value="${MemberBean.mAccount}"
                     size="10"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>密碼:</td>
                <td><form:input id="mPassword"  path="mPassword" type="text" value="${MemberBean.mPassword}"
                     size="10"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><input type="submit" value="更新"  > 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is syntax error due to space between `=` and `:` so change query to below by removing space.

```
SET mb.mAccount =:mAccount mb.mPassword =:mPassword WHERE mId =:mId
```

UPDATE :

You are missing comma between mb.mAccount =: and mb.mPassword

Comment: I remove the space but still have same problem and unexpected token: mb
(syntax error) form my DaoImpl upadateMember.

I tried to think how to update current user data  ,it took me one week .
I still do my best to slove this problem
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: It work! it my missing.Thank you fix my HTTP500 problem,Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Next Step! I tried  to think how to update current user data and how to use EL to get mAccount and mPassword  data ,show to updateMember.jsp and click form submit to updatedatabase,I think maybe updatecontroller not get login session,
eclipse console say:

Hibernate: 
    update
        Member 
    set
        mAccount=?,
        mPassword=? 
    where
        mId=?

but my SQL database still not change

Comment: @Yoshi go ahead and create a new question for the next step.  You should link to this question for context (use `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788021`) and then describe the new problem

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
I create a new question right now.

Comment: Sorry.I have a question,now I asked a new question ,but problem is same ,I just add this link,dont need to upload my code again?