# How to use Spring MVC to update my current user data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm beginner to learn spring MVC, Now I have a problem can't solve. I spent a lot of time want to use Spring MVC to update current user data,but always go round in circles.

For Example   login user is [test2] and I want to update mAccount and mPassword,how to get login session and click jsp form to update.What should I do?(mId is Primary Key)

**Now when I click submit to update, but SQL database mAccount and mPassword doesn't have any change.
I think my controller must have problem to get login session,so I can't update what I want.**

Please excuse me for my poor English,Please help me to solve this problem.
I really need help!

**SQL Member database image Link:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgXBG.jpg)

**This is my Question Link:(Full Code inside)**

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57788021)

Dao:

```
public MemberBean getMemberBymId(int mId);
```

DaoImpl:

```
    @Override
public MemberBean getMemberBymId(int mId) {
    MemberBean mb = null;
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    String sql = "FROM MemberBean mb WHERE mb.mId=:mid";
    mb = (MemberBean) session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("mid", mId).uniqueResult();
    return mb;
}
@Override
public void updateMember(MemberBean mb) {

    String hql = "UPDATE MemberBean mb SET mb.mAccount =:mAccount , mb.mPassword =:mPassword WHERE mId =:mId";
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("mAccount", mb.getmAccount()).setParameter("mPassword", mb.getmPassword())
            .setParameter("mId", mb.getmId()).executeUpdate();

}
```

Service:

```
MemberBean getMemberBymId(int mId);

void updateMember(MemberBean mb );
```

Serviceimpl:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public MemberBean getMemberBymId(int mId) {
    MemberBean mb = null;
    mb = dao.getMemberBymId(mId);
    return mb;
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void updateMember(MemberBean mb) {
    if (mb.getmAccount() != null && mb.getmPassword() != null) {
        dao.updateMember(mb);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateMemberForm/{mId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String AddLoginMemberBeantoUpdateForm(Model model,HttpSession session,@PathVariable Integer mId) {
    MemberBean mb = memberservice.getMemberBymId(mId);
    model.addAttribute("MemberBean", mb);
    return "register/updateMember";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/UpdateMemberForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String UpdateMember(@ModelAttribute("MemberBean")MemberBean mb, BindingResult result ) {

    memberservice.updateMember(mb);
    return "index";
}
```

Jsp:

```
    <form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="MemberBean">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>帳號:</td>
                <td><form:input id="mAccount"  path="mAccount" type="text" value="${mb.mAccount}"
                     size="10"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>密碼:</td>
                <td><form:input id="mPassword"  path="mPassword" type="text" value="${mb.mPassword}"
                     size="10"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><input type="submit" value="更新"  > 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Spring MVC is stateless. There is no relation between the MemberBean placed in the model by the GET request and that populated by the POST request. There are various options to address this but best to get an understanding on where the `@ModelAttribute` populated by the post request comes from: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args

Comment: Yoshi, you are in need of tutorials. I advice you to learn from working projects which does not have complex functionality. I created repository for myself as referance you can download, import and run the project. Go through code and understand. [my github repository](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/springsecurity-autologout). Recommend you to go through first two projects.

Comment: Thanks your reply ，Alan and PreveenKumar,I will take  link and github as reference.but I still want to know how to fixed my code to update current user data.This problem let me so tired and anxious.I must slove problem in this week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong,You want to update a Account,I think problem consist of updateMember function.

```
   //Let me show a example update a object.
  Customer customerToUpdate = customerRepository.getOne(id);
  customerToUpdate.setName(customerDto.getName);
  customerRepository.save(customerToUpdate);
  //But your code directly updating a user account without find  the user  which is gonna changed.I could't examine full of codes but ı think problem occurs here.
      memberservice.updateMember(mb);
```

Comment: .Thank your reply!Yes,if login user is test2,I want to update test2  like mAccount or mPassword(or else),but  I don't know how to  fix UpdateMember controller  to get current user data to update.when I click ada&Abc123456 want to change mAccount&mPassword updateMember(mb) connect hql to update.but still not any change.

Comment: you found core problem ,so I click again and again but SQL database still not any change,controller not get test2 object to update.how to fix controller let me so confuse and anxious.this problem spent me 1week ...

Comment: Let's create a function that which is find the Member with mId.Like findUserbymId();.Then reorganize your UpdateMember servis like that  /UpdateMemberForm/{mId} .Then for example you  want update informations user which is id 43 make a post to /UpdateMemberForm/43.Find your user with findbyuser(43) in the post controller.Then overwrite your member informations with informations which you sent.

Comment: R. Tayyip Barbaros,I update my content (add getMemberBymId function) (↑)Could I take a few minutes of your time? Now When I click updateMemberJsp Page,website said HTTP405 Request method 'GET' not supported, so I can't visit the page,What should I do to slove problem

Comment: <form:form method="POST"  modelAttribute="MemberBean"> maybe this line occurs the problem ?

Comment: I think my  public String UpdateMember controller maybe have problem or as you said jsp form:form  occurs the problem,because I add  {mId} and getMemberBymId(mId).(my index <a href="UpdateMemberForm"></a>)

Comment: Thank your reply!Today I try another approach to edit my controller and Daoimpl,Finally slove this problem.